# Stop running a script if a condition matches

Tags: mysql

My Script has to stop, if the database I use contains 'PROD'.

I can do it with stored procedure, but:

1. It's too big
2. If it fails, procedure will not be dropped, but it has to be.

Is there a better aproach or at least an option to drop the procedure if it fails?

My code:

```sql
USE xxx_prod_xxx;

DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists check_if_prod$$
CREATE PROCEDURE check_if_prod()
BEGIN
    DECLARE C VARCHAR(100);

    SELECT DATABASE() INTO C;

    -- check if contains "prod"
    IF(C LIKE '%prod%') THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Shit happens.';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL check_if_prod();
DROP PROCEDURE check_if_prod;
```

Comment: What;s PROD? is that a database name or a table within a database?

Comment: @P.Salmon, it's a possible part of the database name

Comment: Why do you need to drop the procedure? Just create it once, rather than creating it every time you need to do the check.

Comment: @Barmar just to clean up. But if I can't do it like this, I leave it.